# How replace characters in words by dictionary in java?

Tags: java, string, collections, replace, character

I have words, for example:

```
it
your
reality
real
our
```

and some kind of dictionary in which each char is represented by digit, here it is:

```
1 ij    2 abc   3 def
4 gh    5 kl    6 mn
7 prs   8 tuv   9 wxy
        0 oqz
```

what i need is - word representation by digits, like this:

```
it      -> 18
your    -> 9087
reality -> 7325189
real    -> 7325
our     -> 087
```

i know that i should use collections for this, but which one ? **i`m newbie in java** so any examples are welcome!

**UPDATE:** In php there are [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function which can take array for first argument - what will be searched and second argument - what will be replaced, is there any kind of function in java ?

Comment: We all were newbies once, but we learned by trying, not by copying SO answers. I suggest you show us what you have tried, and what your problem is and we'll gladly help you out.

Comment: What do you mean by "copying SO answers" ? And of course simplest solution create Map and iterate through it, but as you can see in updated section i`m looking for str_replace analog in java, because it  should be faster + more readable

Comment: It won't be faster. Strings are immutable in Java. And of course there's a replace method. Have you looked at the javadoc for String? Classes and methods are documented. Read the documentation.

Comment: I would not have written my comment, if the content of your update was in the post when I first read it. Your original question had no source code whatsoever and it sounded like you are looking for a solution you can copy. The answer to your question is no, Java does not have such a method, that replaces contents from one array with the corresponding contents of another array.

Comment: @JBNizet of course String has a replace method, but it can't be used like the OP is used from PHP's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: Ah, yes. My eyes stopped at `str_replace`. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map<Character, Integer>` to associate each char with its digit. Then iterate through the chars of your word, get the corresponding digit, and append it to a StringBuilder.

You could also simply use an array of 26 elements, containing the digit associated with each letter. To get the index of a given char, you would simply use

```
int index = theChar - 'a';
```

It would be more efficient, but maybe a bit less readable.

Comment: is there any kind of array in java with key like set ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Have you read the javadoc for Map? I think that's what you're looking for, as I have indicated in my answer.